# How can I save a variable inside a definition in python?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def thingy(res)

    if res=="food":
        res=0
    if res=="wood":
        res=1
    if res=="metal":
        res=2
    if res=="gold":
        res=3
    if res=="oil":
        res=3

res="food"

thingy(res)

print(res)
```

When I run this it comes up with "food" when i want it to say "0". how can i get this to work?
Many thanks if you are able to help me.

Comment: do you mean 1 or 0?  question is not clear as it stands

Comment: Python uses Pass By Value not Pass By Reference - you may find [this existing question on the topic helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: sorry my bad, i do mean 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, what you want is to assign the return value to the variable:

```
res = thingy(res) # instead of thingy(res)
```

But if you want another option, perhaps you're looking for a global variable?

```
def thingy():
    global res
    if res=="food":
        res=0
    if res=="wood":
        res=1
    if res=="metal":
        res=2
    if res=="gold":
        res=3
    if res=="oil":
        res=3

res = "food"
thingy()
print(res)  # prints "0"
```

In your example, the `res` inside your function is not the same `res` that you defined outside of your function (you could give one of them a different name and it wouldn't matter). In this example, it is, because of the line `global res`.

But in most cases it's simpler and clearer to use the return value.

Answer (score 8):

You need to return the value, and why not to use `dictionary` instead of all the `if` statements, They are the best for this kind of problems:

**Example:**

```
def thingy(res):
    myOptions = {'food':0, 'wood':1, 'metal': 2, 'gold': 3, 'oil': 3}
    return myOptions[res]

res = "food"
res = thingy(res)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assigning to `res` inside the function only changes the parameter `res`; this does not affect `res` outside the function.

Make the function return the result. Assign the value of the function to the variable.

```
def thingy(res):
    if res=="food":
        res=0
    if res=="wood":
        res=1
    if res=="metal":
        res=2
    if res=="gold":
        res=3
    if res=="oil":
        res=3
    return res # <---

res="food"
res = thingy(res) # <---
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks that has really helped. Soz for being a noob :p :)

Comment: Would this still work if i replaced 
res="food"
res = thingy(res) # <---
print(res)
with
bes="food"
bes = thingy(bes) # <---
print(bes)
?

Comment: @user3132416, Yes it does.